# Google site verification for an app on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, google-apps

I have an app that uses the `googlesheets` package, with authentication, so I need to verify it on google per https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?authuser=0

The recommended method is to upload a html file to http://sjgknight.shinyapps.io/boxplotr/here.html - but I don't think that's possible? (just putting it in the same directory as the ui.r and server.r files to upload certainly doesn't work).

Another method is to put a string in the head of the html...which I thought I might be able to do using

```
tags$head(HTML("<meta name=\"google-site-verification\" content=\"[mystringfromgoogle]\" />"))
```

In ui.R But I'm not clear how those work, certainly putting it either just at the top of the file, or within any of the elements doesn't work...I've searched around and can't find any relevant questions, any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try adding the above line that you mentioned in the question? that should ideally help

Comment: Sorry, should've been clearer @amrrs - I did put it both above any of the UI content (so like, as the first line, and then "shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(" etc.).  And I tried dumping it into that first element as a line too but that just broke the whole app.

Comment: you need to mention that `tags$head` inside the `fluidpage` or similar layout in UI, is that what you tried?

Comment: hm, it's this project, [https://github.com/uts-cic/BoxPlotR.shiny/blob/master/ui.R] I tried it directly on line 5, and as an extra line within the block from line 6 (which looks like it has similar stuff in it), both broke the app though... https://github.com/uts-cic/BoxPlotR.shiny/blob/master/ui.R

Comment: hm, it turns out this is done, whether by uploading the file or by putting the head tag in, guess it just didn't register immediately when I tested earlier